# Delete sitecore page for 301 redirect to work

Tags: sitecore

In sitecore, we made a 301 redirect of an existing page to an external page(another domain) using redirect module. It did not work when we tested as the internal page kept loading. But when we deleted the internal page the redirect worked. So is it necessary that a page do not exist for the 301 redirect to work in Sitecore? Is that also the definition  of 301 redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which of the redirects module you used. As far as I know, there is no "official" redirect module from Sitecore (except from what is a part of SXA), but there are multiple redirect modules available e.g. on Sitecore Marketplace.

Most of them works in a way that first Sitecore checks if it can handle the request and only if the Sitecore page (item) does not exist, the redirection part is processed.

I believe it's the same in your case. You wrote that you had to delete the page. If what I wrote above is correct in your case, I believe you could unpublish item (by setting publishing restrictions and publishing restricted item) or rename (and republish) the item instead of deleting it.